# Getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I am getting this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 and this is my code.

WebElement Case_table = driver.findElement(By.id("ServiceCommunityTemplate")); 
        WebElement tablebody= Case_table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));

```
    List<WebElement> rows = tablebody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    Thread.sleep(12000);

    int count = rows.size();
    System.out.println("ROW COUNT : "+count);

    List<WebElement> colHeaderName = rows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th"));
    List<WebElement> colHeader = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ServiceCommunityTemplate']//table/thead/tr[2]/th"));
    System.out.println("total number of Columns are : " + colHeader.size());
    System.out.println("---------------");
    int colcount = colHeader.size();



        for(int i=1; i<count-1; i++){
            List<WebElement> colVals = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("th"));
            for(int j=0; j<colcount-1; j++){
                    System.out.print(colVals.get(j).getText()+ "\t");

                }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Can anyone tell me, why I am getting this error.

Comment: One of your `findElements()` is not finding any elements. If you examine the exact error message, it will tell you which one. To get a better answer, you would have to post a full [mcve].

Comment: You're not getting any rows and hence you're getting the error at the line:
`List<WebElement> colHeaderName = rows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th"));`

Comment: Stacktrace (aka error log) is a very helpful source to identify errors. Its a rule of thumb to provide it asking any questions regarding code failures

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when you are trying to take an element from a list but the list does not have element with given index.

From your exception is it clear that you are trying to get element with index 0 (i.e. first element) but the list size is 0 (i.e. empty list).

it can either happen in line

```
List<WebElement> colHeaderName = rows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th"));
```

which can happen in the code above if you were unable to find WebElement with tag name `tr` in an element `tableBody` (`List<WebElement> rows = tablebody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));`

or in line

```
System.out.print(colVals.get(j).getText()+ "\t");
```

whicn can happen if you were unable to find any `th` elements in one of your rows (            `List<WebElement> colVals = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("th"));`
)